# Directory Traversal in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have been trying to implement a directory traversal in Ruby for part of a bigger program using the simple recursive approach.  However I have found that [**Dir.foreach**](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Dir.html#method-c-foreach) does not include the directories inside of it.  How can I get them listed?

Code:

```
def walk(start)
  Dir.foreach(start) do |x|
    if x == "." or x == ".."
      next
    elsif File.directory?(x)
      walk(x)
    else
      puts x
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Instead of `Dir.foreach` you can use `Dir.glob(start)` or just `Dir[start]`.

Comment: do you want to skip `.` and `..` right? and want to traverse others inside the `start` in each call of `walk(start)`?

Comment: @iAmRubuuu Yes, to avoid infinite recursion.

Comment: @squiguy added one answer,hope it would help you. :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem is that each time you recurse, the path you pass to `File.directory?` is no is just the entity (file or directory) name; all context is lost. So say you go into `one/two/three/` to check if `one/two/three/file.txt` is a directory, `File.directory?` just gets `"file.txt"` as the path instead of the whole thing, from the perspective of the top-level directory. You have to maintain the relative path each time you recurse. This seems to work fine:

```
def walk(start)
  Dir.foreach(start) do |x|
    path = File.join(start, x)
    if x == "." or x == ".."
      next
    elsif File.directory?(path)
      puts path + "/" # remove this line if you want; just prints directories
      walk(path)
    else
      puts x
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Yes, it doesn't print anything at all.  I have been playing around with it for a while.

Comment: Is it going inside each directory?  I feel like I am doing something wrong.  I don't doubt you!

Comment: Say I have a directory on my desktop with a few files.  What I thought the call would do is see that if I started from my desktop and hit that directory it would redo the walk and output the files inside that directory as well.

Comment: Very nice!  Hmm...I wonder why Ruby wasn't treating it as a directory name and has to have the entire path checked in the directory method?

Comment: Because the path is relative to the current working directory. It's an operating system thing not a Ruby thing. Check [`Dir.chdir`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Dir.html#method-c-chdir) for more information. Basically, if you give `File.directory?` the parameter `"file.txt"`, it's going to only search the current working directory (usually the directory the program is in unless you changed it). So if you want to see if `somedir/file.txt` is a directory, and you only give it `file.txt`, it'll only search in the current working directory and not in `somedir` for that file.

Comment: I see.  I never would have thought of that.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 16):

For recursion you should use [Find](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/find/rdoc/Find.html):

From the documentation:

> The Find module supports the top-down traversal of a set of file paths.
>
> For example, to total the size of all files under your home directory, ignoring anything in a “dot” directory (e.g. $HOME/.ssh):

```
require 'find'

total_size = 0

Find.find(ENV["HOME"]) do |path|
  if FileTest.directory?(path)
    if File.basename(path)[0] == ?.
      Find.prune       # Don't look any further into this directory.
    else
      next
    end
  else
    total_size += FileTest.size(path)
  end
end
```

Comment: Nice find.  I never knew about this.